# Runner crashing on iOS 17 or XCode 15

Tags: ios, flutter, ios17

I updated my simulator to iOS 17 and it seems like ably_flutter plugin is causing the app to crash.

---

### `Translated Report (Full Report Below)`

`Incident Identifier: C0BCD28B-3A18-4C4B-B256-A59CA67A1FE9`
`CrashReporter Key:   63E056BF-A6D7-4F36-E579-7E979A26D26E`
`Hardware Model:      MacBookAir10,1`
`Process:             Runner [28875]`
`Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4A8288E0-4C18-4BA1-B7E1-5A545340F8C3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/59E518EC-2C42-4E6E-8D61-86EA77B4DB65/Runner.app/Runner`
`Identifier:          com.example.testProj`
`Version:             1.0.0 (1)`
`Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)`
`Role:                Foreground`
`Parent Process:      launchd_sim [1037]`
`Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.4A8288E0-4C18-4BA1-B7E1-5A545340F8C3 [1170]`
`Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1024]`

`Date/Time:           2023-09-21 22:39:45.4080 +0800`
`Launch Time:         2023-09-21 22:39:45.3117 +0800`
`OS Version:          macOS 13.5.2 (22G91)`
`Release Type:        User`
`Report Version:      104`

`Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)`
`Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000`
`Termination Reason: DYLD 4 Symbol missing`
`Symbol not found:` *`OBJC_CLASS`*`$_NSError`
`Referenced from: <0F6D1449-FE01-365E-91C7-063615A4EA66> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4A8288E0-4C18-4BA1-B7E1-5A545340F8C3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/59E518EC-2C42-4E6E-8D61-86EA77B4DB65/Runner.app/Frameworks/ably_flutter.framework/ably_flutter`
`Expected in:     <21D37F1A-A952-3927-9A66-03AB5B219B53> /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4A8288E0-4C18-4BA1-B7E1-5A545340F8C3/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/59E518EC-2C42-4E6E-8D61-86EA77B4DB65/Runner.app/Frameworks/Ably.framework/Ably`
`(terminated at launch; ignore backtrace)`

`Triggered by Thread:  0`

`Kernel Triage:`
`VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage`
`VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage`
`VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage`
`VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage`
`VM - (arg = 0x0) pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage`

`Thread 0 Crashed:`
`0   dyld                                  0x10485f118 __abort_with_payload + 8`
`1   dyld                                  0x10486ad7c abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 104`
`2   dyld                                  0x10486adb0 abort_with_payload + 16`
`3   dyld_sim                              0x104a35f50 abort_with_payload + 40`
`4   dyld_sim                              0x1049fc074 dyld4::halt(char const*, dyld4::StructuredError const*) + 300`
`5   dyld_sim                              0x1049fa178 dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 2504`
`6   dyld_sim                              0x1049f93a0 _dyld_sim_prepare + 928`
`7   dyld                                  0x1047f3d88 dyld4::prepareSim(dyld4::RuntimeState&, char const*) + 1328`
`8   dyld                                  0x1047f264c dyld4::prepare(dyld4::APIs&, dyld3::MachOAnalyzer const*) + 276`
`9   dyld                                  0x1047f1e18 start + 1964`

`Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):`
`x0: 0x0000000000000006   x1: 0x0000000000000004   x2: 0x000000016b6eaee0   x3: 0x00000000000001ee`
`x4: 0x000000016b6eaae0   x5: 0x0000000000000000   x6: 0x000000016b6e9980   x7: 0x000000016b6ea540`
`x8: 0x0000000000000020   x9: 0x0000000000000011  x10: 0x0000000000000000  x11: 0x6e206c6f626d7953`
`x12: 0xff786b61402e6a71  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x00000001050f8408  x15: 0x000000016b6e9c18`
`x16: 0x0000000000000209  x17: 0x000000000000001e  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000`
`x20: 0x000000016b6eaae0  x21: 0x00000000000001ee  x22: 0x000000016b6eaee0  x23: 0x0000000000000004`
`x24: 0x0000000000000006  x25: 0x0000000000000b70  x26: 0x000000016b6ec2b0  x27: 0x0000000000000101`
`x28: 0x000000016b6ed018   fp: 0x000000016b6eaaa0   lr: 0x000000010486ad7c`
`sp: 0x000000016b6eaa60   pc: 0x000000010485f118 cpsr: 0x00001000`
`far: 0x00000001047b8000  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault`

Already tried creating a new flutter project and only added ably_flutter plugin and crashes also occur.
https://pub.dev/packages/ably_flutter%60

Answer (score 0):

Many packages are incompatible with the latest version. I was also facing the same kind of issue with a package called [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview).

The easiest way to solve,

1. If possible find some alternatives
2. Open the issue in Git Hub to the package maintainer.
3. If they don't reply and you are good with flutter then make a fork and solve it.

Answer (score 0):

actually, this is a problem that has happened to me but I have solved it by adding this version alternative to the old version.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REUaV.png)

```yaml
 flutter_inappwebview:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/nesquikm/flutter_inappwebview
      ref: heads/v5.7.2+3_fix_xcode_17**
```